# add date to ad text adwords

Tags: scripting, google-ads-api

I want to create ad that change the date every day.
this is the script that I am running every day at 00:00:

```
var date_format = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/y")
var AD_GROUP_NAME = 'ארונות הזזה';
function main() {
  var adGroup = getAdGroup(AD_GROUP_NAME);
  var keywords = adGroup.keywords().get();
  while (keywords.hasNext()) {
    var keyword = keywords.next();
    keyword.setAdParam(1, date_format);
  }
}
function getAdGroup(name) {
  var adGroupIterator = AdWordsApp.adGroups()
      .withCondition('Name = "' + name + '"')
      .withLimit(1)
      .get();
  if (adGroupIterator.hasNext()) {
    return adGroupIterator.next();
  }
}
```

and in the ad I added a text that is including {param1}.
This is not working, do you know why?

Thank you,
Omry.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to do it.
You should check ad customizer instead of ad params.
Have a look.
https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/features/ad-customizers

Here you have a really nice examples. :)